# Replacing url in anchor tag inside email template html running automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, email-templates

I am facing an issue while sending an email with a template containing anchor tag with href setting dynamically before sending. Here is my code to replace placeholders.

```
private string PopulateBody(string userName, string title, string url, string description)
{
    string body = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate.htm")))
    {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    body = body.Replace("[UserName]", userName);
    body = body.Replace("[Title]", title);
    body = body.Replace("[Url]", url);
    body = body.Replace("[Description]", description);
    return body;
}
```

**HTML template**

```
<td style="width:85px;text-align:center;margin:0;padding:0;" width="85" align="center">
   <a href="{{feedback1}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;">
   <img src="{{Stars}}" alt="1 star" style="max-width:60px" border="0" />
   </a>
</td>
<td style="width:85px;text-align:center;margin:0;padding:0;" width="85" align="center">
   <a href="{{feedback2}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;">
   <img src="{{Stars}}" alt="2 star" style="max-width:60px" border="0" />
   </a>
</td>
<td style="width:85px;text-align:center;margin:0;padding:0;" width="85" align="center">
   <a href="{{feedback3}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;">
   <img src="{{Stars}}" alt="3 star" style="max-width:60px" width="60" border="0" />
   </a>
</td>
<td style="width:85px;text-align:center;margin:0;padding:0;" width="85" align="center">
   <a href="{{feedback4}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;">
   <img src="{{Stars}}" alt="4 star" style="max-width:60px" border="0" />
   </a>
</td>
<td style="width:85px;text-align:center;margin:0;padding:0;" width="85" align="center">
   <a href="{{feedback5}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;">
   <img src="{{Stars}}" alt="5 star" style="max-width:60px" border="0" />
   </a>
</td>
```

**Content Replace Code**

```
var templateDirectoryPath = string.Format("{0}EmailTemplates\\DST\\{1}", root, "survey-email-new.html");
     var feedback = string.Format("{0}", "http://www.example.com");
    var content = new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText(templateDirectoryPath));        
    content.Replace("{{feedback1}}", feedback + "feedback?token=" + Base64Encode(query + "1"));
                        content.Replace("{{feedback2}}", feedback + "feedback?token=" + Base64Encode(query + "2"));
                        content.Replace("{{feedback3}}", feedback + "feedback?token=" + Base64Encode(query + "3"));
                        content.Replace("{{feedback4}}", feedback + "feedback?token=" + Base64Encode(query + "4"));
                        content.Replace("{{feedback5}}", feedback + "feedback?token=" + Base64Encode(query + "5"))
```

I have placed some code in the url action method when someone visit that link i.e change status etc. Problem is that when an email is sent automatically this link fires . I have logged to see what is happening but the url got hit as soon as email is received and it is invoking that action method.

Need help.

Comment: `Problem is that when an email is sent automatically this link fires` - Since a link cannot automatically "fire", I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Also you're not mentioning how can included URL can be "automatically accessed" from body  - something that seems impossible without user action. Explain what  `EmailTemplate.htm` contains & which action method fired by that URL.

Comment: I have updated with html and content replace code.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar kind of issue.

So at the end I've just replaced the anchor tag with the URL itself. When the HTML rendered in the email, the URL worked like a link.

Instead of 
 `<a href="{{URL}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;">`

this can be used

`<p>{{URL}} </p>`